# How to shuffle in same order?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, shuffle

I have two ArrayList, the one is a Bitmap typ and contains picture and the other is a String which contains the text for the bitmap.

I just want to shuffle the Bitmap, but the String ArrayList should be in the same order.

```
private ArrayList<Bitmap> tmpBitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
private ArrayList<String> tmpName = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I tried this, but it shuffles in different orders.

```
Collections.shuffle(tmpWord);
Collections.shuffle(tmpName);
```

Comment: I think you mean you want two parallel lists to have identical shuffles. You would be better off putting your related items into objects and not using parallel lists.

Comment: How do you mean? Can you post an example code?

Comment: In theory, you could create two java.util.Random instances with the same seed, and specify one of them on the first shuffle, the other on the second shuffle. Given the same length and same sequence of pseudo-random numbers, shuffle will produce the same permutation. Getting rid of the parallel lists by combining the fields into a single object is likely to result in more maintainable code.

Comment: You could use a third List of Integers, which represented the index points into the other two lists. You'd shuffle this list and use what ever value you retrieved from this list as the index into the other two...

Answer (score 4):

I said in the comments that you would be better off putting the strings and bitmaps into objects together so you don't need to maintain parallel lists. Here is basically how that would be:

```
class NamedBitmap {
    String name;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    // use privacy modifiers and accessors according to your taste
    public NamedBitmap(String name, Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.name = name;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
}

List<NamedBitmap> namedBitmaps = new ArrayList<NamedBitmap>();

...

Collections.shuffle(namedBitmaps);
```

This way the names are always tied to the bitmaps; you don't have to keep two lists in the same order to keep them associated.

Parallel arrays (or lists) are how people had to associate related data in a time before structs and objects provided better options.

*Edit*:

Given a `List<NamedBitmap> namedBitmaps` as described above, you can add stuff into it using:

```
namedBitmaps.add(new NamedBitmap(givenName, givenBitmap));
```

and you can access the names and bitmaps using `namedBitmaps.get(i).name` and `namedBitmaps.get(i).bitmap`.

Comment: Parallel lists are often a warning sign that two or more fields that belong in the same object are being handled separately. They are also a risk during program maintenance: someone, someday may do something to one list but not the other.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but what should I type in the class? I draw the Bitmap in onDraw and I also read the text for it from an array list. In the array I have list of text for bitmap 0-29.

Comment: @Unknown See my edit. If that's not what your looking for, you'll have to be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 2):

Change your two ArrayLists to a `Map<Bitmap,string>` collection then when you shuffle you get both shuffled as you expect and only have to access one collection to get all the information you need. Although this does require that the bitmaps are unique

*Thanks to kcoppock for noticing it was Android / Java

Comment: Right enough didn't notice the Android / Java tags :P

Comment: You'd still need one `List` in order to shuffle them; you can't typically shuffle a `Map`.

Comment: You could initialize a `List` from the `Map` `entrySet()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
long seed = new Random().nextLong();
Collections.shuffle(tmpWord, new Random(seed));
Collections.shuffle(tmpName, new Random(seed));
```